# Help me to recover the seed ! pdfuniformdeviate

Tags: pdftex, pdf, random-numbers

I made a BIG mistake : I compiled a file and used some macro with `pdfuniformdeviate`. But I did not realized I will need to recompile this (official) document with the SAME random sampling.

I keep all the file from the first compilation (log, aux, pdf). Is there a way to recover the seed from those files and set it to ensure the next compilation will all use the same original seed ?

Comment: Probably not.  How were results of `\pdfuniformdeviate` used in your macro?  Can the successive values be somehow extracted?

Comment: Yes but it will take a very large amount of time. I think I just lost my next week-end to a very repetitive task :)

Comment: If it's repetitive, then quite possibly it can be programmed.  It might make for an interesting question...

Comment: If I'm reading the source code correctly, the random seed is calculated from the system time as `(microseconds*1000)+(epochseconds mod 1000000)`. So unfortunately you won't be able to recover the seed from the time in the `.log` file (the random seed in `pgfmath` only changes every minute, so that would have been easier).

Comment: IF @Jake is correct, then presumably you could set up a (shell) script to try all of these various microsecond-epochsecond combinations (within a reasonable timespan) and then compare the outputs of LaTeX (again, scripted... diff?).

Comment: If you did not use the value for a cryptographic hash function maybe there is a way to calculate the original value back from the output in the pdf document. Maybe you can give a bit more information what your macro does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the comments: recovering the seed here will be extremely tricky as it comes from the system time with formula

```
(microseconds*1000)+(epochseconds mod 1000000)
```

You could in principle run a script testing the possibilities until you 'hit' the correct one, assuming you have some idea roughly where to start.